# How can I generate client-side view models for knockout in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC solution and have recently introduced both Knockout (an MVVM JS library) and Wijmo (a set of jQuery UI widgets).

With the introduction of Knockout I also need to have models on the client side, so for this purpose I am serializing the C# ViewModel and attaching it to the view using `data-model="@Model.ToJson()"`. This allows me to retrieve the model from JS and apply some client-side love to everything.

However, knockout needs everything to be observables, so I need to declare a separate client-side ViewModel and map everything from the data-model object. This feels very much like duplicate effort and I'd like to avoid it somehow.

I'm hoping someone has a tool or technique to share that will allow me to render the knockout ViewModel directly from the server. Possible solution could include:

- Custom JSON serialization to render the observable view model directly to the output in the data-model attribute.
- Automatic client-side transformation (I've heard of ko-autobind, but am not sure if it would be a recommended path to take or how stable/complete it is)
- Something I haven't thought of

I'd like the solution to be generic and automatic, as my current approach of typing the observable client-side view models by hand is just too unproductive to be viable.

How are you solving this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to their tutorials it's just a simple `.map` function

If this is the ViewModel

```
function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
}
```

And this function get's the data from the server, it uses the `.map` function to inject the server data right into the VM

```
// Data
var self = this;
self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

// Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
$.getJSON("/tasks", function(allData) {
    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) {
        return new Task(item)
    });
    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
});
```

For ko mapping
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

For auto-bind here's an example

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/IJTx37UXQVw/UTrWdEK1C-oJ

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm already doing, as you need a Task function for every view model. The solution I'm looking for shouldn't require me to have a method or class for every view model, but rather have a single shared piece of code to do the transformation (either client or server side). Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: That's where you want the autobind I believe it was called, or yes otherwise you need to have one for each :-(

Comment: Does autobind work? It was last updated 7 months ago and the readme says "This is intial commit and supports only binding element names to viewmodel", and this seems to imply that stuff is missing or that some cases wont work, without being very explicit about it. Also, the jsfiddle that the author linked to in another post was broken, so could use an example if that's your recommendation ;)

Comment: here's some info on the site http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and here is the Git repo, shows at version 2.1.2 from a month ago By Steve S https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output

Comment: Looks like ko-mapping is the better choice

Comment: ko-mapping is indeed exactly what I was looking for! Very nice, thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to define the client side view model, have it be dynamically created? Also interested in EF data annotations being available on the client side to double up for client side validation. I know breezejs does something similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Try this pluggin for visual studio
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32c15a80-1c54-4e96-a83f-7cd57573a5d2